# How can I use to the stream extraction operator to read a file assuming that only the last line will have errors of not containing 3 values

Tags: c++

TEXT FILE IM READING

```
1 1 1
1.2 -2.3 0.4
-2 -3 -4
+0 -2 8.85
2.345
```

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

double readFile(ifstream &myfile, double &a, double &b, double &c);
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    double a, b, c;
    string line, inputFile, outputFile;

    cout << "Enter the name of your input file: ";
    cin >> inputFile;

    cout << "Enter the name of your output file: ";
    cin >> outputFile;

    ifstream myfile(inputFile);
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while(!myfile.eof())
        {
            readFile(myfile, a, b, c, counter);
            calculations(a, b, c);
        }


    }
    else cout << "unable to open file";
    return 0;
}

double readFile(ifstream &myfile, double &a, double &b, double &c)
{
    //Reads one line of the file
    myfile >> a >> b >> c;
    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;

}
```

What i want to do is that if the last line does not have 3 values i want to have some sort of stop code where it stops the processing if it has less than 3 values and the leftovers values from the previous line wont be assigned

Comment: First see [Why !.eof() inside a loop condition is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539)

Comment: Then, turn on warnings, you should get one for `readFile()` method's returning nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that `>>` skips leading whitespace, so it doesn't differentiate between a `' '` (space) or `'\n'` -- it's just whitespace. To handle it correctly, you need to read each line into a `std::string` and then create a `std::stringstream` from the line.

Then read your three `double` values from the `std::stringstream` with `>>`. That way you can read no more `double` values than are present in the line. Otherwise if you just try and use `>>`, you will happily read 2 `double` values from one line and the third from the next without any indication of that happening.

You next need your function to indicate success/failure of reading the three `double` values from the line. A return type of `bool` is all you need. If you read three valid `double` values, return `true` and do your `calculations()` otherwise, if you return `false`, stop trying to read from the file.

A short example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

bool read3doubles (std::ifstream& f, double& a, double& b, double& c)
{
    std::string line {};                /* std::string to hold line */
    
    if (getline (f, line)) {            /* if line read from file */
        std::stringstream ss(line);     /* create stringstream from line */
        if (ss >> a >> b >> c)          /* if 3 doubles read from line */
            return true;                /* return true */
    }
    
    return false;   /* otherwise, return false */
}

void calculations (double& a, double& b, double& c)
{
    std::cout << a << "  " << b << "  " << c << '\n';
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least 1 argument given */
        std::cerr << "error: insufficient number of arguments.\n"
                    "usage: " << argv[0] << " <filename>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);          /* open file-stream with 1st argument */
    double a, b, c;
    
    if (!f.good()) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        std::cerr << "errro: file open failed '" << argv[1] << "'.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    while (read3doubles(f, a, b, c))    /* while 3 doubles read from file */
        calculations (a, b, c);         /* do your calculation */
    
}
```

(**note:** the `calculations()` function just outputs the three doubles when successfully read)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your input in the file `dat/3doubles.txt`, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/read3doubles dat/3doubles.txt
1  1  1
1.2  -2.3  0.4
-2  -3  -4
0  -2  8.85
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks for explaining what was wrong with my code and how I could improve it

Answer (score 1):

`std::istream` sets `failbit` when `operator>>` failed to extract value from stream. In your code, `failbit` will be set if it fails to parse 3 values that can be parsed into double, and you can query if `failbit` is set by `std::failbit()`.

```
double readFile(ifstream &myfile, double &a, double &b, double &c)
{
    myfile >> a >> b >> c;

    if(myfile.fail())
    {
        // failbit is set if one of a, b or c is not parsed successfully.
        // do some stop code here.
    }

    cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << endl;

}
```

Remember, `std::istream` does nothing for further operation if `failbit` is set. If you're needed to continue reading from the stream, you should clear `failbit` by calling `std::clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a different function that chops a line by space and converts them to numbers. Your main function remains largely unaffected. Though I made some changed like adding a `std::vector`, early return to remove some nesting.

Also, I changed the main `while` condition from `eof` to `std::getline`.

- Operations on `std::string_view` are very cheap.
- This way you can check on *every line* that the number of values read is always what you need.
- For bad input, you can easily debug if a line/ word is not number by printing it in the exception catcher.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void read_values(std::string_view line, std::vector<double> &values);
void calculations(int, int, int);
int main()
{
  string inputFile, outputFile;

  cout << "Enter the name of your input file: ";
  cin >> inputFile;

  cout << "Enter the name of your output file: ";
  cin >> outputFile;

  ifstream myfile(inputFile);
  if (!myfile.is_open()) {
    cout << "unable to open file";
    return -1;
  }

  std::string line;
  std::vector<double> values;
  while (std::getline(myfile, line, '\n')) {
    read_values(line, values);
    std::cout << values.size();
  }
  return 0;
}

void read_values(std::string_view line, std::vector<double> &values)
{
  while (!line.empty()) {
    const std::string_view::size_type pos_space{line.find(' ')};
    try {
      values.push_back(std::stod(std::string(line.substr(0, pos_space))));
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument &ex) {
      std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
      return;
    }
    line.remove_prefix(pos_space + 1);
  }
}
```